# Mocking `document` in jest

Tags: jestjs, jsdom, babel-jest

I'm trying to write tests for my web components projects in jest. I already use babel with es2015 preset. I'm facing an issue while loading the js file. I have followed a piece of code where `document` object has a `currentScript` object. But in test context it is `null`. So I was thinking of mocking same. But `jest.fn()` is not really help in same. How can I handle this issue?

Piece of code where jest is failing.

```
var currentScriptElement = document._currentScript || document.currentScript;
var importDoc = currentScriptElement.ownerDocument;
```

Test case I have written. `component.test.js`

```
import * as Component from './sample-component.js';

describe('component test', function() {
  it('check instance', function() {
    console.log(Component);
    expect(Component).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Following is the error thrown by jest

```
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null

      at src/components/sample-component/sample-component.js:4:39
```

**Update:**
As per suggestion from Andreas Köberle, I have added some global vars and tried  to mock like following

```
__DEV__.document.currentScript = document._currentScript = {
  ownerDocument: ''
};
__DEV__.window = {
  document: __DEV__.document
}
__DEV__.document.registerElement = jest.fn();

import * as Component from './arc-sample-component.js';

describe('component test', function() {
  it('check instance', function() {
    console.log(Component);
    expect(Component).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

But no luck

**Update:** I have tried above code without `__dev__`. Also by setting document as global.

Comment: Have you tried using `global.document`?

Comment: yes..i have tried that..no luck..

Comment: So I basically used jsdom like
`const jsdom = require('jsdom');

const documentHTML = '<!doctype html><html><body><div id="root"></div></body></html>';
global.document = jsdom.jsdom(documentHTML);
`
And after this I tack on anything I want to the document and its available in my tests.

Comment: actually problem here is, jsdom is very simple and doesn't have webcomponents API. Anyways temporarily resolved it as per my answer.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Similar to what others have said, but instead of trying to mock the DOM yourself, just use JSDOM:

```js
// __mocks__/client.js

import { JSDOM } from "jsdom"
const dom = new JSDOM()
global.document = dom.window.document
global.window = dom.window
```

Then in your jest config:

```json
    "setupFiles": [
      "./__mocks__/client.js"
    ],
```

Comment: `TypeError: _jsdom.JSDOM is not a constructor`

Comment: they must have changed their API since a year ago?

Comment: looks like `new JSDOM()` is still correct - maybe you have something else configured incorrectly, like babel? https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom

Comment: they don't put changelogs with releases so hard to tell https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/releases

Comment: The changelog is at https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/master/Changelog.md

Comment: Yes you need to have babel-jest and @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs.

It still works with Jest 24 (I use ts-jest) and is great to mock other global variables like window.navigator or navigator :-)

Answer (score 25):

I have resolved this using `setUpFiles` property in jest. This will execute after jsdom and before each test which is perfect for me.

Set setupFiles, in Jest config, e.g.:

```
"setupFiles": ["<rootDir>/browserMock.js"]


// browserMock.js
Object.defineProperty(document, 'currentScript', {
  value: document.createElement('script'),
});
```

Ideal situation would be loading webcomponents.js to polyfill the jsdom.

Answer (score 19):

I have been struggling with mocking document for a project I am on. I am calling `document.querySelector()` inside a React component and need to make sure it is working right. Ultimately this is what worked for me:

```js
it('should test something', () => {
  const spyFunc = jest.fn();
  Object.defineProperty(global.document, 'querySelector', { value: spyFunc });
  <run some test>
  expect(spyFunc).toHaveBeenCalled()
});
```

Answer (score 7):

If like me you're looking to mock document to undefined (e.g. for server side / client side tests) I was able to use object.defineProperty inside my test suites without having to use setupFiles

Example:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  Object.defineProperty(global, 'document', {});
})
```

Comment: I tried to mock `document.referrer` and `document.URL` by providing them in the object...no luck.  The properties still showed up as their usual values in test runner.

Comment: @theUtherSide I've noticed this solution working in some versions of Node and not others. Maybe install NVM and have a play with different versions

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I'll play with Node version and post some findings!  I really like this strategy better than using the Jest config. I work on a big team, and it's better to keep our unit tests isolated and, of course atomic!

Comment: Confirming -- The app where I tried this is using Node v8.11.1 and Jest 21.2.1

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot redefine property: document` => `      at JSDOMEnvironment.teardown (node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/build/index.js:192:14)`

Answer (score 6):

If you need to define test values for properties, there is a slightly more granular approach.  Each property needs to be defined individually, and it's also necessary to make the properties `writeable`:

```
Object.defineProperty(window.document, 'URL', {
  writable: true,
  value: 'someurl'
});
```

See: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/890

This worked for me using Jest `21.2.1` and Node `v8.11.1`

Answer (score 6):

This is the structure in my project named **super-project** inside the folder **super-project**:

---

- **super-project**

  - config

    - `__mocks__`

      - dom.js
  - src

    - user.js
  - tests

    - user.test.js
  - jest.config.js
  - package.json

---

You need to setup Jest to use a mock in your tests:

**dom.js**:

```js
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom"
const dom = new JSDOM()
global.document = dom.window.document
global.window = dom.window
```

**user.js**:

```js
export function create() {
  return document.createElement('table');  
}
```

**user.test.js**:

```js
import { create } from "../src/user";

test('create table', () => {
  expect(create().outerHTML).toBe('<table></table>');
});
```

**jest.config.js**:

```js
module.exports = {
  setupFiles: ["./config/__mocks__/dom.js"],
};
```

---

**References:**

You need to create a manual mock:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks.html

Manipulating DOM object:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-jquery

Jest Configuration:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration

Answer (score 3):

I could resolve this same issue using `global` scope module on nodejs, setting document with mock of document, in my case, `getElementsByClassName`:

```
// My simple mock file
export default {
    getElementsByClassName: () => {
        return [{
            className: 'welcome'
        }]
    }
};

// Your test file
import document from './name.component.mock.js';
global.document = {
    getElementsByClassName: document.getElementsByClassName
};
```

Comment: yep..that does but its very simple usecase...in webcomponents.js we have large set of API interconnected. Mocking them is one hell of a task...

Comment: But in your case, what you need mock exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution. Let's say inside of your component you want to get a reference to an element in the DOM by className (document.getElementsByClassName). You could do the following:

```
let wrapper
beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<YourComponent/>)
    jest.spyOn(document, 'getElementsByClassName').mockImplementation(() => 
        [wrapper.find('.some-class').getDOMNode()]
    )
})
```

This way you are manually setting the return value of getElementsByClassName equal to the reference of .some-class. It might be necessary to rerender the component by calling wrapper.setProps({}).

Hope this helps some of you!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Object.defineProperty(global.document, 'visibilityState', {
        configurable: true,
        writable: true,
        value: {
            get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('visible'),
        },
    });
```

Comment: Please provide some context, code only answers are rarely useful

Comment: Please read [answer] and take the [tour].

Answer (score -2):

Hope this helps

```
const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
const render = shallow(<MockComponent{...props} />);
document.getElementById = jest.fn((id) => {
      wrapper.innerHTML = render.find(`#${id}`).html();
      return wrapper;
    });
```

Comment: This answer assumes the Component is a React Component. I don't see anything that indicates this. It looks like a plain javascript web component to me.