# Mock document in Jest test file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha, jestjs

I have this method in a react component to load the [Google Recaptcha API](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/android.html) when componentDidMount.

```
loadCaptcha = () => {
  ((d, s, id) => {
    const element = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    const fjs = element;
    let js = element;
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
      return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = '//google.com/recaptcha/api.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  })(document, 'script', 'google-recaptcha');
};
```

I'm having problems mocking `document` in a Jest test file because `d` has only `Document { location: [Getter/Setter] }` and, for that, the other objects are `undefined`.

I have tried adding `setupFiles` in Jest config, as [other people said in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098009/mocking-document-in-jest):

`"setupFiles": ["<rootDir>/__mocks__/documentMock.js"]`

*documentMock.js:*

```
Object.defineProperty(document, 'currentScript', {
  value: document.createElement('script'),
});
```

But with no luck. Has someone fixed that?

Also tried this:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  global.document: { //code }
})
```

Pd: This is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
```

Thanks.

Comment: you were close, just use JSDOM instead of trying to mock the dom manually :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use setupFiles with jsdom:

**__mocks__/client.js**

```
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom"
const dom = new JSDOM()
global.document = dom.window.document
global.window = dom.window
```

Then in your jest config:

```
"setupFiles": [
  "./__mocks__/client.js"
],
```

Answer (score 5):

There is [no need to manually mock JSDOM in Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-jquery). It will be automatically mocked if you select default `testEnvironment` inside `jest.config.js` file which is:

```
testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
```

If you would like to use some DOM features not implemented in JSDOM just mock them following [official docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom), e.g.

```
window.matchMedia = jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => {
  return {
    matches: false,
    media: query,
    onchange: null,
    addListener: jest.fn(),
    removeListener: jest.fn(),
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got here to specifically mock `currentScript`, and couldn't find the exact right answer.

This was the solution for me:

**./setupTests.ts**

```
// Mock current script to be able to spy on it
Object.defineProperty(document, 'currentScript', {
  configurable: true,
  get() {
    return document.createElement('script');
  },
});
```

**testFile.spec.ts**

```
describe('Test Suite', () => {
  afterEach(() => jest.clearAllMocks());

  it('should test byproduct of document.currentScript.src', () => {
    jest.spyOn(document, 'currentScript', 'get').mockReturnValue({ src: '' } as any);

    // ... run code
  });
});
```