# Jest with jsdom, document is undefined inside Promise resolve

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, jsdom

**The scenario**

Trying to test a simple React component using Jest (and Enzyme). This component uses `react-dropzone` and I want to test some operations involving the DOM so I use jsdom (as already configured by `create-react-app`)

**The problem**

The `document` object while available in the my test code and also available inside of the component, is `undefined` inside of the dropzone `onDrop` callback, which prevents the test from running.

**The code**

*MyDropzone*

```
import React from 'react'
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone'

const MyDropzone = () => {
    const onDrop = ( files ) =>{
        fileToBase64({file: files[0]})
            .then(base64Url => {
                return resizeBase64Img({base64Url})
            })
            .then( resizedURL => {
                console.log(resizedURL.substr(0, 50))
            })
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Dropzone onDrop={onDrop}>
                Some text
            </Dropzone>
        </div>
    );
};

const fileToBase64 = ({file}) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = () => {
            return resolve(reader.result)
        }
        reader.onerror = (error) => {
            return reject(error)
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    })
}

/**
 * Resize base64 image to width and height,
 * keeping the original image proportions
 * with the width winning over the height
 *
 */
const resizeBase64Img = ({base64Url, width = 50}) => {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    canvas.width = width
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    const img = new Image()

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        img.onload = () => {
            const imgH = img.height
            const imgW = img.width
            const ratio = imgW / imgH
            canvas.height = width / ratio
            context.scale(canvas.width / imgW, canvas.height / imgH)
            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
            resolve(canvas.toDataURL())
        }

        img.onerror = (error) => {
            reject(error)
        }

        img.src = base64Url
    })
}

export default MyDropzone;
```

*MyDropzone.test.jsx*

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone'

import MyDropzone from '../MyDropzone'

describe('DropzoneInput component', () => {
    it('Mounts', () => {
        const comp = mount(<MyDropzone />)
        const dz = comp.find(Dropzone)
        const file = new File([''], 'testfile.jpg')
        console.log(document)
        dz.props().onDrop([file])
    })
})
```

*setupJest.js*

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
```

**Config**

- Default `create-react-app` jest config with `setupJest.js` added to `setupFiles`
- Run: yarn test

**Error**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
    at resizeBase64Img (C:\dev\html\sandbox\src\MyDropzone.jsx:44:29)
    at fileToBase64.then.base64Url (C:\dev\html\sandbox\src\MyDropzone.jsx:8:20)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

**More info**

Consider that `document` is always defined if running that code in the browser, so to me the issue seems related with jsdom or Jest.

I am not sure if it is related with Promises, with the FileReaded or with the JS scope in general.

Maybe a bug on Jest side ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098009/mocking-document-in-jest

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue reading file on disk with a promise using jest.

Comment: Everything is proper in jest setup. Using jsdom for document in test environment. Except for inside promise where document is null everywhere else document is defined.

Comment: @Zword, can you give a minimal repo for debugging? It would be much faster

Comment: @TarunLalwani [here ya go](https://github.com/mikepatrick/jsdom-js-demo).  Interestingly enough, I found this was easy to reproduce with a JS app, but not with a [TS app](https://github.com/mikepatrick/jsdom-ts-demo).

Comment: How are you running the tests? I did `npm test` and then `a` and all the tests passed for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBWVJ.png, `node -v -> v8.9.4` and `npm -v  -> 5.7.1`

Comment: I'm just doing `yarn test`.  I consistently observe this behavior when I clone a fresh copy of my sample repo:  Using `yarn`, (for install and test) the tests pass the first two times I run them, and then consistently fail.  Using `npm`, the tests pass the first time I run them, and then consistently fail.  Do these tests _consistently_ pass across multiple runs for you?  I'm using `node v8.9.4`, `npm v5.6.0`, and `yarn v1.3.2`.

Comment: Didn't get a notification for your last comment. Looking into this now

Answer (score 6):

So I was able to resolve this. The assumption that it works without any config changes is wrong. First you need to add few more packages added. Below is my updated `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "js-cra",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.2.9",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "jest-enzyme": "^6.0.0",
    "jsdom": "11.10.0",
    "jsdom-global": "3.0.2"
  }
}
```

Also I removed `--env=jsdom` from the test script. As I was not able to make it work with that combination

After that you need to create a `src/setupTests.js`, which is load globals for your tests. This where you need to load `jsdom` and `enzyme`

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import 'jest-enzyme';
import 'jsdom-global/register'; //at the top of file , even  , before importing react

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

After that your tests would error out with below error

```
/Users/tarun.lalwani/Desktop/tarunlalwani.com/tarunlalwani/workshop/ub16/so/jsdom-js-demo/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/test.js:20
  throw err;
  ^

ReferenceError: FileReader is not defined
```

The issue seems to be that `FileReader` should referred with a `window` scope. So you need to update it like below

```
const reader = new window.FileReader()
```

And then run the tests again

[image: Working tests]

Now the tests work fine

Comment: This may have helped for some thats why I am awarding the bounty but on importing jsdom-global I am getting this error `Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget'`

Comment: Can you update the exception? I had a similar one when I forgot to remove `--env=jsdom` from `package.json`

Comment: I removed --env=jsdom and its giving me other errors like window.scrollTo is failing

Comment: I ran the test on the repo you had shared, that why I wanted the repo on the first place

Comment: Well this is my actual code: https://github.com/JesselJohn/react-components/. You can try on this one

Comment: The only failures I get are because of `React does not recognize the animationDuration prop on a DOM element`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170156/discussion-between-zword-and-tarun-lalwani).

Comment: Sorry @TarunLalwani I didn't have time yet to test this out. I will accept the answer soon. There are a few things that bugs me though. Maybe you can elaborate: 1) what is the actual reason that causes document to be undefined2) I am not very happy to remove --env=jsdom and install js-dom global (as it doesn't sound the 'suggested' way of testing with enzyme 3) prepending window.<something> also doesn't make me happy. I mean: if it works fine when promises are not involved, why should we we change all the non-test code (so source code) just to make jest behave? Thanks anyways for the debugging