# How to mock document object with Jest / Enzyme in a React constructor?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to improve codecoverage for a bit of React code which looks kind of like this:

```
export default class WuTangClan {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setState(this.getCookie('36chambers'));
  }

  getCookie(name) {
    const value = `;${document.cookie}`;
    const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
    let toReturn;
    if (parts.length === 2) {
      toReturn = parts
        .pop()
        .split(';')
        .shift();
    }
    return toReturn;
  }  
}
```

Here's the piece from codecov which I'm struggling with:

[image]

Using enzyme, if I were to `mount(<WuTangClan />)`, it would then run through `getCookie`. Here's issue - that function relies on `document` and because jest runs in the context of node I can't seem to mock it. Meaning, `document` is empty when Jest tests are running and so I can't get it to jump in.

I've tried every answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098009/mocking-document-in-jest) to no avail.

Jest "~22.2.2"
Enzyme "^2.5.0"
Node "8.8.0"

Comment: Have you tried importing JSDom and setting window.document equal to the jsdom mock before your tests run?

Answer (score 0):

If your only issue is about setting cookies then you can do so like below:

```js
it("should return cookie", () => {
    global.document.cookie = "cookie1=foo"; //set cookies in whatever format you like
    document.cookie = "cookie2=bar";
    let page = shallow(<WuTangClan />);
    
    // run assertions here;
  });
```