# Jest mock documentElement lang property

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to manipulate documentElement lang property for my tests. 
And can't figure it out how can I accomplished that. I've already tried  defining setupFiles in Jest config - and that gave me possibility to define it and no option to change it for different tests - as described here: [Mocking `document` in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098009/mocking-document-in-jest)

Part of testing **code** looks like:

```
const lang: string = document.documentElement.lang ?
      document.documentElement.lang : Constraints.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
```

The **test** look like this:

```
   test('should pass `en` language when document hasn`t any specified', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(window.document, 'documentElement', 'get');
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

And with **setupFiles**:

```
Object.defineProperty(document, 'documentElement', {
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    value: document.createElement('document')
});
```

When I have setupFiles I get error:
`Property documentElement does not have access type get`

But when I try to spy on it without `setupfile.js` configured, spy is never called.

**EDIT**

More clear example what I'm trying to achieve:

```
    const lang: string = document.documentElement.lang ?
      document.documentElement.lang : Constraints.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
    component.src = `/${lang}/mysite`;
```

```
test('should pass `de` language when document has one specified', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(window.document, 'documentElement', 'get');
    const mockElement = document.createElement('document');
    mockElement.lang = 'de';
    spy.mockReturnValue(mockElement);
    expect(component.src).toContain('/de/');
  });
```

And in test I'm getting:

```
expect(received).toContain(expected) // indexOf

    Expected substring: "/de/"
    Received string:    "http://localhost/en/mysite"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well you are almost there, but when you access `document.documentElement.lang` property, the get accessor has been triggered. So you should define that object like below;

```
Object.defineProperty(document, 'documentElement', {
    configurable: true,
    get () {
        return document.createElement('document');
    },
});
```

And in your test;

before expect line you should add this line to trigger getter and make spy to be called.

```
window.document.documentElement.lang;
```

**EDIT**

Forget about above.

Simply remove your setup code block, you don't need a spy or something in my opinion.

Create a method for setting language into your constant. Then test that method instead of testing `get` action of documentElement.

Use the code for setting lang property below before calling your method. (Imagine you have language method)

```
test('should return `de` language when document has one specified', () => {
    Object.defineProperty(document.documentElement, 'lang', { value: 'de', configurable: true });

    expect(component.language()).toBe('de');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But that is not exactly answer to my problem. I need to change document.documentElement.lang property (please, see edit example)

Comment: I added edited code according to your need. You may need small refactor in your code, but this will help i think.