# Testing LightningChartJS with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, lightningchart

I'm attempting to create a Jest test that tests the implementation of a class that instantiates a LightningChartJS ChartXY.

The following error is thrown during the instantiation of the Chart:

```
  EngineError: Null pointer in i
  ...
  at new i (../../node_modules/@arction/lcjs/dist/lcjs.js:1:8948)
  at Ot (../../node_modules/@arction/lcjs/dist/lcjs.js:1:20740)
  at new i (../../node_modules/@arction/lcjs/dist/lcjs.js:1:458125)
  at ../../node_modules/@arction/lcjs/dist/lcjs.js:47:49973
  at Object.ChartXY (../../node_modules/@arction/lcjs/dist/lcjs.js:47:211838)
  at new LightningPlot (src/app/lightningChart.ts:70:8)
```

[This GH issue hints](https://github.com/Arction/lcjs-example-0200-candlesticks/issues/1) at the source of the problem: LightningChartJS does not find the respective DOM node to insert into.

What I've tried so far:

- Import jest-canvas-mock into the setup (necessary to enable canvas in JSDom and avoid [this issue](https://github.com/hustcc/jest-canvas-mock/issues/2))
- using a JSDom import during setup to mock the DOM ([based on this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50629802/1792564))
- Using the Jest testEnvironment `jest-environment-jsdom`configuration

The DOM mock was tested in several ways:

- using createElement()
- setting innerHTML of the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSDOM alone is not enough to be able to run LightningChart JS outside of browser environment. JSDOM doesn't provide WebGL support so when LightningChart JS calls `canvas.getContext('webgl')` it will not receive the context and will throw an error. To be able to run LCJS with Jest, the `canvas.getContext` method needs to be edited a bit to support WebGL.

You will need to install [`gl`](https://github.com/stackgl/headless-gl) and [`canvas`](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) npm packages and then add a setup file to your Jest configuration.

`__setups__/lcjs.js`:

```js
const createContext = require('gl')
// overwrite getContext to return headless-gl webgl context
const orig_getContext = window.HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext
window.HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = function () {
    if (arguments[0] === 'webgl') {
        // create headless-gl GL context
        const ctx = createContext(1, 1, arguments[1])
        // insert the resize method to the context so that lcjs package can use it
        ctx.resize = ctx.getExtension('STACKGL_resize_drawingbuffer').resize
        return ctx
    } else {
        return orig_getContext.apply(this, arguments)
    }
}
```

Jest configuration:

```
{
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "./__setups__/lcjs.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

Using that setup file will make it possible for LightningChart JS to run in the environment Jest provides. The setup file is based on [`lcjs-headless`](https://github.com/Arction/lcjs-headless) implementation.

Comment: Nice, thank you! I'll attempt to integrate your solution and get back to you.