# Unable to mock document attributes in jsdom when using ts-jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, jsdom, babel-jest

I'm using Jest with `ts-jest` in a `jsdom` environment. I want to mock the object, which is returned by `document.adoptedStyleSheets`. This property is not yet supported by `jsdom`.

I'm unable to mock the property in any way. Every attempt always results in `document.adoptedStyleSheets` being `undefined`. In fact, I'm unable to mock anything returned from document. Is the object write-protected?

The most similar question to my post would be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098009/mocking-document-in-jest), however TypeScript with ts-jest is not being used and I assume this is the root of my problem.

My current mocking implementation looks like this, it is executed in a `beforeAll()`-block:

```js
    Object.defineProperty(document, 'adoptedStyleSheets', {
      // mock
    });
```

However, the `document.adoptedStyleSheets` value stays at `undefined`.

`jest.config.js`

```js
    /** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
    export default {
      preset: 'ts-jest',
      testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
      transform: {
        '^.+\\.tsx?$': ['ts-jest', {
          tsconfig: 'tsconfig.test.json',
        }]
      },
      setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest-setup.ts']
    };
```

`jest.setup.ts`

```
    import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

`tsconfig.test.json`

```json
    {
      "include": [
        ".plasmo/index.d.ts",
        "./**/*.ts",
        "./**/*.tsx",
        "./jest-setup.ts"
      ],
      "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "paths": {
          "~*": [
            "./src/*"
          ]
        },
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "esModuleInterop": true
      },
    }
```